# IOException: Can't read input file. I couldn't find solution using different paths, even manually

Tags: java, image, path, io

How to resolve this error ?  I couldn't find solution using different paths, even manually. Please explain how to read an image into the buffered image using absolute path.

```
private BufferedImage[] image = new BufferedImage[9];
private int imageNo = 0;
private Boolean draw = false;
private int drawType;
private String [] realtivePath;
private String [] absolutePath;
//=============================================================================

public DrawPanel() {

    int i,j; 
    absolutePath =  new String[9];
    realtivePath = new String []{"B_Pictures\\Burj Khalifa.jpg", "B_Pictures\\Taipei 101.jpg", "B_Pictures\\Willis Tower.jpg",
        "B_Pictures\\Empire State Building.jpg", "B_Pictures\\Chrysler Building.jpg",
        "B_Pictures\\Woolworth Building.jpg", "B_Pictures\\Met Life Tower.jpg",
        "B_Pictures\\Singer Building.jpg", "B_Pictures\\Philadelphia City Hall.jpg"}; 
    //======================================================================
    for(i = 0;i < 9; i++)
    {
        absolutePath[i] = new File(realtivePath[i]).getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Path is: "+absolutePath[i]);
    }
   //=======================================================================
    try {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            image[j] = ImageIO.read(new File(absolutePath[j])); //<-- can't read absolute path!
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of reasking, update your question and ask for some attention.

Comment: Should I remove this one then ? Thanks for advise.

Comment: You should at least include the error you're getting and the output your System.out.println is creating.

Comment: @Edi: No, leave it for this time. But keep in mind :)

Comment: Here is a first line of an output regarding file path:            Path is: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\Sorting_Ass4\B_Pictures\Burj Khalifa.jpg
And an error that occured:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at GUI.DrawPanel.<init>(DrawPanel.java:49)
 at GUI.GUI_Control.<init>(GUI_Control.java:36)
 at GUI.Main.main(Main.java:15)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)                                Thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IO file path error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108464/io-file-path-error)

Answer (score 4):

obviously your absolute paths are incorrect.  you are resolving the relative paths based on the directory in which you are running your java application.  apparently those are the wrong relative paths (or you are running the app in a different location than you think you are).

UPDATE:

as a clarification, `File.getAbsolutePath()` makes a relative path absolute if it is currently relative.  *this is a purely textual change* and does not imply any validity for the resulting absolute path.  e.g. if you have a relative path "foo/bar" and you make it absolute based on the current directory "/blah", then your resulting absolute path is "/blah/foo/bar".  *that does not imply that "/blah/foo/bar" is a valid path*.

Here's an easy way to check your code:

```
System.out.println("Path is: "+absolutePath[i] + ", isReadable " + new File(absolutePath[i]).canRead());
```

Comment: Can you explain it based on solution. How can they be incorrect as they are generated by a method that returns absolute path?

Comment: I have provided first string with relative path that is: B_Pictures\Burj Khalifa.jpg  which is a package in java netbeans that contains all jpeg images. Based on this relative path I have used getAbsolutePath()  method to obtain absolute path that is: C:\Users\foo\Desktop\Sorting_Ass4\B_Pictures\Burj Khalifa.jpg for example above mentioned. Even without obtaining absolute path and instead using it hardcoded with escape sequence it does not work. What is my absolute path?

Comment: @Edi - since i'm not on your computer, i can't tell you what the correct path is.  once you figure it out though, your code should start working.

Comment: It returns false in each case.

Comment: I knew you were gonna say it :)

Comment: I have just used:                                System.out.println(new File(absolutePath[i]).isAbsolute() ? "is absolute path":"is not absolute path");  and the output is that it is absolute path.

Comment: @Edi - i don't think you understand my answer.  an "absolute" path just means that it is not "relative" to any directory.  _it does not mean it is the correct path_.  you need to find the _correct_ absolute path.  canRead() returning false means that your paths are wrong (absolute or relative does not matter).

Comment: Problem:
C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\Sorting_Ass4\\B_Pictures\\Burj Khalifa.jpg

Solution:
C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\Sorting_Ass4\\**src**\\B_Pictures\\Burj Khalifa.jpg <--- working absolute path.